# How to change the file extension for phpdocumentor 2 twig writer

Tags: phpdocumentor2

I'm trying to output markdown instead of html with a phpDocumentor 2 template.  I am outputting markdown fine but not able to change the filename extension for classes.

The `artifact` makes sense when it's a single transformation. When `query=indexes.classes`is used how does it decide that the filename should be `[class].html`?

I've tried `artifact="{CLASS}.md"`, `artifact="{{CLASS}}.md"`, `artifact=".md"` but it always treats them literally.

`<transformations>
        <transformation query="indexes.classes" writer="twig" source="templates/docsify-twig/class.md.twig" />
        <transformation writer="twig" source="templates/responsive-twig/reports/markers.html.twig" artifact="markers.html"/>
      </transformations>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a matter of reading the code.  From

https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/blob/develop/src/phpDocumentor/Plugin/Twig/Writer/Twig.php

````
 * A complex example transformation line could be:
 *
 *     ```
 *     <transformation
 *         query="indexes.classes"
 *         writer="twig"
 *         source="templates/twig/class.twig"
 *         artifact="{{name}}.html"/>
 *     ```
````